# Brake hood mirror for Specialized bicycle

Tags: mirrors

Are there any brake hood mirrors available that will fit the Tiagra shifters on my Specialized bicycle?  I can't tell exactly what model they are; but, they say "Tiagra Double" on the front.  The bicycle is about 10 years old (maybe a bit older).

(I have tried a couple mirrors that go in the handle bar ends, and they don't work well.  They don't stay in position, so I don't get a good view behind me.  My 30-year-old Fuji bicycle has a mirror that mounts to the brake cable, and it works wonderfully.)

[image: My shift lever]

Comment: Have you tried the "CORKY Performance Rear Mirror"? It's another bar end mirror, but seems to work well...

Comment: A friend uses a mirror on the helmet.